# Is Chutzpah Test Adapter not available for VS 2013 Express Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, chutzpah

I want to use the Chutzpah Test Adapter to run Jasmine tests in VS 2013 Express edition. I am using TypeScript with AngularJS in a Web Api project.

I have used Chutzpah Test Adapter successfully in VS 2012 Ultimate edition elsewhere but I cannot get the Test Adapter in the Tools > Extensions and Updates. Also the download from the Chutzpah site does not install it for the VS 2013 Express edition.

If Chutzpah does not work for VS 2013 Express, does anyone know of any alternatives for unit testing TypeScript code in VS 2013 Express Edition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio Express editions do not support [third party extensions](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/05/21/no-extensions-for-visual-studio-express.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Matthew. Do you know if I can still use Chutzpah in VS 2013 Express for unit testing TypeScript code? In the past I had wired up Google Tests (for testing C++ code in VS 2010) to run as an executable in post-build events. Do you think I can do something like that for Chutzpah?

Comment: Totally. Chutzpah has an .exe runner that you can use.